# How do I calculate $E[X^2Y]$ for discrete (and DEPENDENT) random variable given the joint pmf table?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

So far I have found the marginal pmf for X and Y and proved that the random variable are not independent by showing that;

$P(X=i, y=j)\neq P(X=i)P(Y=j)$

The next question asks to calculate;

$E[X^2Y]$

To calculate this I'm using the following property;

$Cov(X,Y) =E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$

So in relation to my question;

$E(X^2Y) = Cov(X^2,Y)+E(X^2)E(Y)$

I have calculated $E(X^2)$ & $E(Y)$

To calculate the $Cov(X^2,Y)$

can I use the following formula for discrete RV;

$Cov(X,Y)=\sum \sum_{(x,y)\in S} (x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)f(x,y) $

where f(x,y) is the joint pmf

and simply replace the expectation of x with the second moment of x?

ie.

$Cov(X^2,Y)=\sum \sum_{(x,y)\in S} (x^2-\mu_x^2)(y-\mu_y)f(x,y) $

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: If you know $P(X=i,Y=j)$, then can you not use the formula $E[X^2Y] = \sum_{i,j} i^2 \times j \times P(X= i,Y=j)$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг there are situations where things become easyer if you work with standardized random variables. Then covariances come in sight. That might explain the preference (not sure of that) of the OP.

Comment: In the equality following "So in relation to my question" the minus-sign must be a plus-sign.

Answer (score 2):

Use $E(X^2Y)=\sum_i\sum_jP(X=i, Y=j) i^2j$.

Comment: This could turn out to be a good advice, but is actually not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but then you must be precise:$$\mathsf{Cov}(X^2,Y)=\mathbb E(X^2-\mathbb EX^2)(Y-\mathbb EY)=\sum_x\sum_y(x^2-\mu_{X^2})(y-\mu_Y)f(x,y)\tag1$$

Note that in $(1)$ we have $\mu_{X^2}=\mathbb EX^2$ and **not** $\mu_X^2=(\mathbb EX)^2$.